# Where to put different style file for tablet with bigger resolution

Tags: android

I have in /res/values/styles.xml different font styles but I need to change that for tablet. Where to put that new style file with same names if resolution if tablet is 1280x800 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder in res/ and name it values-xlarge/.
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html